# Visual Studio 2017 Multiple Build Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a strange problem in VS2017.

I have a project which consists of multiple projects. To keep it simple lets say i have a Class Library and WPF Application. WPF uses Class Library.

WPF is set as Startup Project.

I make a change in Class Library and Run.

The change isnt compiled and therefore WPF uses the old code base.

Stop

Run Again and everything is fine.

I've never come across this before. Any ideas?

James

Comment: It's not new. E.g. even though you have unit tests not compiling you can often run the app.

Comment: Have you used the `Class Library` in code-behind? or just in `XAML`?

Comment: Used in code. Hardly in XAML.

Comment: You forgot to set up project [dependencies](http://dailydotnettips.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/image63.png), make wpf [depends](http://dailydotnettips.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/image64.png) on class library.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the solution in Visual Studio, choose `Configuration Manager` and check that the `Build` checkbox is checked for both projects for the active solution configuration.

Comment: All checked as it should be.

Comment: What if you rebuild?

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me. Did you try to clean?

Answer (score 0):

In the end we removed the project reference and re added and it suddenly worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Create object of that class in MainWindow.xaml.cs(or if you have your own Window) and make a call to those methods from class which you want to execute in MainWindow.xaml.cs